# How to set default Textstyle in flutter_quill package?

Tags: flutter, quill

My requirement is to force flutter a particular text style in my application, but I cant find a option for that in *QuillTool.basic*

```
Column buildEditor() {
return Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: quill.QuillEditor.basic(

            controller: _controller, readOnly: false)),
    quill.QuillToolbar.basic(
      fontSizeValues: const {'Small': '12'},
        controller: _controller,
      showAlignmentButtons: false,
      showBackgroundColorButton: false,
      showCameraButton: false,
      showCenterAlignment: false,
      showClearFormat: false,
      showCodeBlock: false,
      showColorButton: false,
      showDirection: false,
      showDividers: false,
      showFontFamily: false,
      showFontSize: true,
      showFormulaButton: false,
      showHeaderStyle: false,
      showImageButton: false,
      showIndent: false,
      showInlineCode: false,
      showJustifyAlignment: false,
      showLeftAlignment: false,
      showLink: false,
      showListCheck: false,
      showListNumbers: false,
      showQuote: false,
      showListBullets: false,
      showSearchButton: false,
      showStrikeThrough: false,
      showVideoButton: false,
      showSmallButton: false,
    )
  ],
);
```

}

At current situation it's giving an 12 size default size output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it by using the `customStyles` property of `QuillEditor`:

```
                               QuillEditor(
                                          controller: _controller2,
                                          readOnly: false,
                                          showCursor: true,
                                          autoFocus: false,
                                          expands: false,
                                          placeholder: 'add title',
       //This property with paragraph ->  customStyles: quill.DefaultStyles(
                                      ->      paragraph:
                                                  quill.DefaultTextBlockStyle(
                                                      TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.black,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900,
                                                          fontSize: 35),
                                                      Tuple2(16, 0),
                                                      Tuple2(0, 0),
                                                      null),
```

For `Tuple` you'll need to import [tuple](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple) package.